I cannot use sqlite3 on visual studio code for a C++ project
I'm trying to use SQLite3 for a project in C++ in Windows. I have already installed  sqlite3.h, sqlite3.c, sqlite3.def, sqlite3.dll and sqlite3.exe and imported into my project' folder.
enter image description here
However, I still have the same problem as before, which is like this:
enter image description here
I'm trying to build those two files myself, but I have no idea how to do it: I tried with this command on the developer command prompt: lib /DEF:sqlite3.def /OUT:sqlite3.lib /MACHINE:x64, for the first error, but it didn't work.
If someone could help me solving this problem, i'm going to be really grateful because i'm currently freaking out.

Well one error is that there should be a space between -lwinsock32 and -lws2_32

I might be wrong, but I think you can just delete -lsqlite3

Ok thanks, I didn't noticed. For the first one?

Replace -lsqlite3 with sqlite3.c, there is no sqlite library you just compile the downloaded sqlite3.c file

I did it and it showed me a lot of errors. sqlite3.c:204835:20: sqlite3.c:204824:16: note: forward declaration of 'struct jsonEachBestIndex(sqlite3_vtab*, sqlite3_index_info*)::sqlite3_index_constraint'
const struct sqlite3_index_constraint pConstraint;
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
sqlite3.c:204842:26: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'const struct jsonEachBestIndex(sqlite3_vtab, sqlite3_index_info*)::sqlite3_index_constraint'
}else if( pConstraint->op==SQLITE_INDEX_CONSTRAINT_EQ ){
^~
And a lot more
